# How would I use a button on my app to set the current URL that a WebView is showing?

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview, nsbutton

How would I use a button on my app to set the current URL that a WebView is showing?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the [[UIWebView request] url] and then set it to the title of the button.

[UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/request) and [NSUrlRequest](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001695-BJBGGFJD)